# Getting information about openings from forge model

Tags: autodesk-forge

Is it possible to read information about openings from a forge model?

I have an IFC file that is translated to a forge model. When reading information about the elements in this model I cannot find the openings. In IFC the element type is IfcOpeningElement. This information is not located in the modelview properties. I have also tried to use the Extractor, but there is no inforamtion about this in the properties database. What I need is the GlobalID and the name of the openings.

Comment: is this a direct ifc --> forge translation? no revit or anything else involved?

Comment: In my test I have created the ifc from Revit, but that is not always the case.

Comment: the development team is asking for a reproducible case, i.e., a minimal sample model and the exact sequence of steps from the original seed CAD model to the Forge translation. they say: which Navisworks or Revit version are you using? could you please share the IFC Model with us? best add the RVT as well. thank you!

Answer (score -1):

It seems that openings are currently not supported by the translation pipeline. Sorry about that.

Comment: Any news on this one? We are starting a new project and reading information about holes and other relations between objects is essensial.